# Getting "[CDS] shutdownInput in read" in logCat

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-networking

I have an android application which I am developing and at a certain stage I am getting

`" [CDS]shutdownInput in read "` continuously in my Log Viewer?

What is this entail and what am I doing wrong to cause this message to appear?

I have a thread checking the in stream.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                mySocket.ReadFromSocket();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


public byte[] ReadFromSocket() throws IOException {
    if (socketState == SocketState.CONNECTED) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int noOfBytesRead = nis.read(buffer, 0, 1024); // This is blocking
        while (noOfBytesRead == -1) {
            noOfBytesRead = nis.read(buffer, 0, 1024); // This is blocking
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        byte[] tempdata = new byte[noOfBytesRead];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tempdata, 0, noOfBytesRead);
        return tempdata;
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Socket Not Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: nope none yet. I gave up on that particular piece of code.

Comment: In fact I tried to close the socket, shutdown the input, and interrupt the thread but nothing works. In fact the upcoming move will be uninstall and reinstall the app and I afraid they will still exist

Answer (score 0):

This error message shows whenever a TCP connection tries to read from a buffer and the other side has dropped the connection. Usually after a timeout if you are sending data out.checkError() will return true